# Proxy requests in a vue.js application

Tags: vue.js

**In vue.js to make Cross-Origin Resource Sharing(CORS) requests, we can configure a proxy rule in the vue.config.js file:**

vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
//configure webpack-dev-server behavior
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/api': ''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Considerations:

**My Vue client application run on http://localhost:8080, my api server run on http://localhost:3000**.

```
'/api': { target: 'localhost:3000' ........ }
```

All requests made to /api' from within my vue application will be forwarded to target: 'localhost:3000'

So if there are requests that start with /api resource path, these requests will be proxied to the target address: localhost:3000

for example:

request localhost:8080/api will be proxied to localhost:3000/api

request localhost:8080/api/1 will be proxied to localhost:3000/api/1 and so on.

```
pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' }
```

^/api is a regex.

pathRewrite matches /api path in the target address and replaces it (/api) with empty string

for example, proxied request to localhost:3000/api/1 will become localhost:3000/1

`changeOrigin: true` enable CORS requests

At the end, With the above proxy rule, every requests starts with /api :(localhost:8080/api, localhost:8080/api/1 ..........) will be proxied to localhost:3000, localhost:3000/1 ........

are my considerations correct??

The official documentation is not very clear.

Thanks

Comment: `changeOrigin` does not impact CORS but the `host` header. The rest is correct.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. What does "not impact CORS but the host header",   mean?

Comment: It has nothing to do with CORS, it impacts the value of the HTTP `host` header. Webpack dev server does not handle CORS at all, it is something you have to configure on the server where your API is hosted.

Comment: ok, so changeOrigin:true allows me to set the host header value, in the http request, to a specific value. Right? which value??

Comment: No you cannot choose the value. When setting true, it "changes the origin of the host header to the target URL"

Comment: "host header" is a header in the http request?